# Is VB's Dim the same as C#'s var?

Tags: c#, vb.net

This is a small doubt: On VB, I can declare variables using Dim. In C#, I can declare then using `var`. I'm more familiar with the intricacies of C#, and I know that `var` uses *type inference* to determine the type of the variable. But I'm not sure what 'Dim' does.

I've seem [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127738/what-is-the-equivalent-of-vbs-dim-statement-in-c) on SO, but it doesn't compare both keywords. If there's a difference, can someone tell me which?

Comment: For more clarification in addition to what you've already come across, research early vs. late binding.  That's the difference between the two at the core.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That depends if [`Option Infer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx) is specified.  Normally, the following are equivalent:

```vb
'VB.Net
Dim myVar
Dim myString = "Hello world!"
Dim myString2 As String = "Hello world!"
```

```csharp
//C#
object myVar;
object myString = "Hello world!"; //Notice type is object, *not* string!
string myString2 = "Hello world!";
```

However, with `Option Infer` enabled, `Dim` becomes more like `var` when the variable is initialized on the same line:

```vb
'VB.Net
Option Infer On
Dim myVar
Dim myString = "Hello!"
```

```csharp
//C#
object myVar;
var myString = "Hello!"; //Or the equivalent:  string myString = "Hello!";
```

Note that this can lead to some confusion because suddenly initializing a variable at the point of declaration means something different from initializing it later:

```vb
'VB.Net
Option Infer On
Dim myVar1
myVar1 = 10
Dim myVar2 = 10

myVar1 = New MyClass() 'Legal
myVar2 = New MyClass() 'Illegal! - Value of type 'MyClass' cannot be converted to 'Integer'
```

This can be fixed by enabling [`Option Strict`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs%28VS.80%29.aspx), which (among other things) forces all variables to be given a type *(implicitly or not)* at the time of declaration.

Comment: With `Option Infer On` code such as `Dim myVar1` no longer works: `Infer On` and `Strict Off` are mutually exclusive (unless they changed that in VB10).

Comment: @Konrad: I'm pretty sure that's not true.  The [VB9 documentation for `Option Infer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665%28VS.90%29.aspx) makes explicit mention that `Option Strict` can be `On` or `Off`.  Also, I just tested it and it works fine.

Comment: Then I must have a wrong memory. Weird … I was quite certain that the compiler complained if `Infer` was used without `Strict`.

Answer (score 14):

They are not the same. `Dim` in VB simply means that what follows is a variable declaration.

For example, these two are equivalent:

```vb
Dim x As String = "foo"
```

```csharp
string x = "foo"
```

In `C#`, var means that a variable declaration’s type is inferred by the compiler based on usage (initialisation). The same can be achieved in VB by simply omitting the type of the declaration. However, this also requires that `Option Strict` and `Option Infer` are activated:

```vb
Dim x = "bar" ' Compiler infers type of x = string
```

```csharp
var x = "bar" // same here.
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends, in vb.net you write

```
dim x = 1
```

then it's the same as c# var.

Or you can write

```
dim x as integer = 1
```

which is the same as c#

```
int x = 1;
```

As from vb.net 9.0 you don't need to have the type with an initialize statement

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364068(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There's [this from Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsVarDim.aspx)

> For c# var:
>
> ...[var is] a new keyword that means,
> "I want to declare a variable, but I’m
> too lazy to write out its type."
>
> One way to look at the power of VB's
> Dim operator is to say,
>
> Dim kind of means, "I want to declare
> a variable but I can't tell you much
> about how it behaves until much
> later."
>
> Dim lets you do actual late-binding while in C# (today) you do late-binding with reflection.

Answer (score 1):

The `Dim` in VB doesn't do anything itself, its just a keyword that means the rest of the statement is to do with declaring a variable.  Its a `BASIC` keyword from the mists of time meaning 'dimension' when you couldn't declare ordinary variables, but you did have to declare the 'dimension' of arrays.

If, in your mind's eye, you ignore the `Dim` and compare what's left you'll find VB and C# pretty similar, except that C# does it the wrong way round (You can guess which language I grew up with) and, like C, puts the type first (or uses `var`) and the name of the variable next.

Answer (score 0):

`Dim` means 'dimension', and is used in VB.Net to declare a variable. It basically implies  'Reservce some/enough space to hold one a type of *_*_'. The datatype comes in later; usually on the same line.

`var` in C#, as you mentioned, is actually a shortcut to tell the compiler to infer the data type based on the value first assigned.

Comment: I thought it meant "declare in memory"

Comment: @Steve; yup, you got it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033507/what-does-dim-stand-for-in-visual-basic-and-basic

Answer (score 0):

the var keyword is specifically typed by the datatype it is assigned in the variable.
But dim is invariant which can be used for any type.

Comment: var tells the compiler that you are wanting to declare a specific type keep in mind that C# is Type specific not like vb which is Type / object interpreted "STAY AWAY FROM VB"