# vb.net datatable loop through rows by specific column name

Tags: vb.net

Hi i am trying to loop through row only in specific column. However i did not succeed, can any one help me.
Here is my code, myXvalue = "CPI" is the column header Name.

```
Dim myXvalue = "CPI"

 For Each column As DataColumn In dt.Columns


                If column.ColumnName = myXvalue Then

                    For k As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows(myXvalue).Count - 1

                        Console.WriteLine(myXvalue & " === " & dt.Rows(0)(k).ToString)


                    Next

                    Console.ReadKey(True)


                End If
```

Comment: you are looping on the columns not rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a. In visual basic.net a better practice is to define the types of fields or propeties.
 use `Dim myXvalue As String = "CPI"` and not `Dim myXvalue = "CPI"`.
if you familiar with c# this convention is not exactly like `var` in c#:
 [Is VB's Dim the same as C#'s var?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678909/is-vbs-dim-the-same-as-cs-var)

b. the code below is one way to achieve what you need.

```
Private Sub Func()
    Dim myXvalue As String = "CPI"
    Dim colIndex As Integer = -1

    For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
        If dt.Columns(i).ColumnName = myXvalue Then
            colIndex = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If colIndex = -1 Then
        ' only for safty if this column name is not exist
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        Console.WriteLine((myXvalue & "===" & dt.Rows(i).Item(colIndex).ToString()))
    Next

    Console.ReadKey(True)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathana this what i was looking for :)

Comment: Hi Jonathana while extracting these data (dt.Rows(i).Item(colIndex).ToString()) to text file its taking only 2 decimals and skipping rest, Do i need to format the cells to take entire value ?

Comment: that wasent part of the question but try to cast it to double: `CType(dt.Rows(i).Item(colIndex).ToString(), Double).ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
    If dr.Item("myColumnHeaderName").ToString = "certainColumnValue" Then
        Console.WriteLine(dr.Item("myColumn").ToString())
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score -1):

With this you get a list of all Items from one Column

```
Dim col_allitems as string = myData.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Select(Function(row) row.Item(1).ToString)
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation with you answer. This way, OP can also learn and not simply copy and paste.