# Loop through non-array JSON with dynamic object IDs using Newtonsoft Json.NET

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm using the [Newtonsoft JSON library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002297/getting-the-name-key-of-a-jtoken-with-json-net). I want to loop through a JSON result set **without** having to create a separate class if possible, since the JSON object is far more extended that displayed here.

I already looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002297/getting-the-name-key-of-a-jtoken-with-json-net) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46530913/newtonsoft-json-loop-through-jarray).

My JSON (beautified at bottom of post):

```
Dim json As String = "{""result"":{""a326f402f18ab1cd2c4489b07cc3e8f4"":{""id"":""a326f402f18ab1cd2c4489b07cc3e8f4"",""client_id"":30,""broker"":[{""broker_id"": 30,""name"": ""Andrew"",""emailaddress"": ""andrew@homes.com""}],""photos"":[{""small"":""https://www.example.com/30/photos/small/66.1427790195-976.jpg"",""middle"":""https://www.example.com/30/photos/middle/66.1427790195-976.jpg""},{""small"":""https://www.example.com/30/photos/small/31382.1508417843-454.JPG"",""middle"":""https://www.example.com/30/photos/middle/31382.1508417843-454.JPG""}]},""18aec266ec0c01d126e9715bc17124e2"":{""id"":""18aec266ec0c01d126e9715bc17124e2"",""client_id"":30,""broker"":[{""broker_id"": 30,""name"": ""Andrew"",""emailaddress"": ""andrew@homes.com""}],""photos"":[{""small"":""https://www.example.com/30/photos/small/10.1298385655.jpg"",""middle"":""https://www.example.com/30/photos/middle/10.1298385655.jpg""},{""small"":""https://www.example.com/30/photos/small/10.1298385646.jpg"",""middle"":""https://www.example.com/30/photos/middle/10.1298385646.jpg""}]}}}"
```

I first tried with `JsonTextReader`, but that seemed too cumbersome in trying to access the individual properties quickly:

```
Dim sBuilder As New StringBuilder
Dim reader As JsonTextReader = New JsonTextReader(New StringReader(json))
While reader.Read
    If reader.Value IsNot Nothing Then
        sBuilder.Append(String.Format("Token: {0}, Value: {1}", reader.TokenType.ToString, reader.Value.ToString))
    Else
        sBuilder.Append(String.Format("Token: {0}", reader.TokenType.ToString))
    End If
    sBuilder.Append("<br/>")
End While
```

I then tried to work with `JObject` and `JArray`. The problem there is that the JSON response is generated by a 3rd party and IMO is not formatted well, since the `result` object should actually be an array. Also the results contain dynamic IDs (`a326f402f18ab1cd2c4489b07cc3e8f4` and `18aec266ec0c01d126e9715bc17124e2`)

So, I'm now faced with: how can I loop through all results when `result` is not an array and each result is also identified by a dynamic id?

Pseudo code:

1. Loop through the number of results (in this case 2: `a326f402f18ab1cd2c4489b07cc3e8f4` and `18aec266ec0c01d126e9715bc17124e2`)
2. For each of those results I want to select the attributes. This does not necessarily have to be strongly typed (`json.photos(j).small`), I'd be fine with something like `json(i)("photos")(j)("small")`

_

```
Dim photoSmall As String
Dim clientId As Integer
For i As Integer = 0 To json.count - 1    
    With json(i)
        clientId = json.client_id           
        For J As Integer= 0 To json.photos.count - 1
            photoSmall = json.photos(j).small       
        Next J      
    End With
Next i
```

**Beautified JSON**

```
{
    "result": {
        "a326f402f18ab1cd2c4489b07cc3e8f4": {
            "id": "a326f402f18ab1cd2c4489b07cc3e8f4",
            "client_id": 30,
            "broker": [
                {
                    "broker_id": 30,
                    "name": "Andrew",
                    "emailaddress": "andrew@homes.com"
                }
            ],
            "photos": [
                {
                    "small": "https://www.example.com/30/photos/small/66.1427790195-976.jpg",
                    "middle": "https://www.example.com/30/photos/middle/66.1427790195-976.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "small": "https://www.example.com/30/photos/small/31382.1508417843-454.JPG",
                    "middle": "https://www.example.com/30/photos/middle/31382.1508417843-454.JPG"
                }
            ]
        },
        "18aec266ec0c01d126e9715bc17124e2": {
            "id": "18aec266ec0c01d126e9715bc17124e2",
            "client_id": 30,
            "broker": [
                {
                    "broker_id": 30,
                    "name": "Andrew",
                    "emailaddress": "andrew@homes.com"
                }
            ],
            "photos": [
                {
                    "small": "https://www.example.com/30/photos/small/10.1298385655.jpg",
                    "middle": "https://www.example.com/30/photos/middle/10.1298385655.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "small": "https://www.example.com/30/photos/small/10.1298385646.jpg",
                    "middle": "https://www.example.com/30/photos/middle/10.1298385646.jpg"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

This code returns an array

```
Dim photosTEST As JArray = DirectCast(item("photos"), JArray)
Log("photosTEST length", photosTEST.Count.ToString)
```

But this code throws error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

```
Dim brokers As JArray = DirectCast(item("broker"), JArray)
Log("brokers length", brokers.Count.ToString)
```

I don't understand since `broker` is just an array with length of 1 correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast the `result` `JToken` to a `JObject` and loop through its `Properties()` collection.  The `Value` of each of those properties is another `JObject` containing the data (e.g. `id`, `client_id`, `photos`, etc.) you are interested in.

Here is an example:

```
Dim obj As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
Dim result As JObject = DirectCast(obj("result"), JObject)
For Each prop As JProperty In result.Properties()

    Dim item As JObject = DirectCast(prop.Value, JObject)
    Dim id As String = item("id").Value(Of String)
    Dim clientId As Integer = item("client_id").Value(Of Integer)
    Console.WriteLine("id: " & id)
    Console.WriteLine("client id: " & clientId.ToString())

    Dim brokers As JArray = DirectCast(item("broker"), JArray)
    For i As Integer = 0 To brokers.Count - 1
        Dim broker As JObject = DirectCast(brokers(i), JObject)
        Dim brokerId As Integer = broker("broker_id").Value(Of Integer)
        Dim name As String = broker("name").Value(Of String)
        Dim email As String = broker("emailaddress").Value(Of String)
        Console.WriteLine("broker " & i.ToString() & " id: " & brokerId)
        Console.WriteLine("broker " & i.ToString() & " name: " & name)
        Console.WriteLine("broker " & i.ToString() & " email: " & email)
    Next

    Dim photos As JArray = DirectCast(item("photos"), JArray)
    For i As Integer = 0 To photos.Count - 1
        Dim photo As JObject = DirectCast(photos(i), JObject)
        Dim small As String = photo("small").Value(Of String)
        Dim middle As String = photo("middle").Value(Of String)
        Console.WriteLine("photo " & i.ToString() & " small: " & small)
        Console.WriteLine("photo " & i.ToString() & " middle: " & middle)
    Next

    Console.WriteLine()
Next
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ALeiX8

Note that the code above assumes that all of the object properties in your example JSON will always be present.  If it is possible that a particular property might not appear, then you will need to do a check for `Nothing` on that property before trying to use its value.  For example, you mentioned that you are getting an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error when you try to access the `broker` count.  That tells me that for some of your result items, there is not a `broker` property in the JSON.  In that case, you would need to change the code to check for `Nothing` like this:

```
    Dim brokers As JArray = DirectCast(item("broker"), JArray)
    If brokers IsNot Nothing Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To brokers.Count - 1
            Dim broker As JObject = DirectCast(brokers(i), JObject)
            Dim brokerId As Integer = broker("broker_id").Value(Of Integer)
            Dim name As String = broker("name").Value(Of String)
            Dim email As String = broker("emailaddress").Value(Of String)
            Console.WriteLine("broker " & i.ToString() & " id: " & brokerId)
            Console.WriteLine("broker " & i.ToString() & " name: " & name)
            Console.WriteLine("broker " & i.ToString() & " email: " & email)
        Next
    End If
```

Similarly, if a broker might not have an email address, then you would need to do something like this:

```
            Dim email As String = ""
            If broker("emailaddress") IsNot Nothing Then
                email = broker("emailaddress").Value(Of String)
            End If
```

In fact, if you find that there are many properties in the JSON which you cannot count on always being there, you can write a little extension method to help simplify your code.  This method will allow you to supply a default value to be used in place of a particular `JToken` if it turns out to be `Nothing`:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Module JsonExtensions

    <Extension()>
    Public Function ValueOrDefault(Of T)(token As JToken, defaultValue As T) As T
        If token IsNot Nothing AndAlso token.Type <> JTokenType.Null Then
            Return token.Value(Of T)
        Else
            Return defaultValue
        End If
    End Function

End Module
```

Then you can use it in wherever you are currently using `Value(Of T)` or `DirectCast` on a `JToken`.  For example:

```
Dim brokers As JArray = item("broker").ValueOrDefault(new JArray())
```

Or:

```
Dim email As String = broker("emailaddress").ValueOrDefault("")
```

Comment: Thanks! You code works for `photos` array, but throws an error on `broker` property (see update 2)...could you help me explain why?

Comment: @Flo - I'm guessing the example in your question is just a shortened version of your "real" JSON?  In the updated example you posted, there is no reason you should be getting that error; `broker` is just an array of length 1, as you suggested.  But if you are running this code against a different, longer JSON and that JSON does not always have a `broker` for each result item, then that would result in the error you are seeing.  I updated my answer to explain how you can fix it.

Comment: You were right...rookie mistake, but serendipity: I got a really nice extension method from it :-).
One question on that: I have this in my JSON `"title": null`. When I use your extension method: `name = item("title").ValueOrDefault("")`, the code still fails since variable `name` will be `Nothing` instead of an empty string. How can I alter your extension to solve for that?

Comment: @Flo If the JSON contains an explicit null, we can check for that by looking at the `JToken.Type` property to see if it is `JTokenType.Null`.  I've updated the code for the extension method in my answer.